# Is it Christmas?

Tags: code-golf, date

## Challenge

Given that Christmas is:

- December
- Month 12
- Day 25

Every year, determine today's date, and whether or not today is Christmas.
If it is Christmas, you must print `"It's Christmas"`. If it is not Christmas, you must somehow wait until Christmas and then print `"It's Christmas"`.

## Example

From [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379805/im-new-to-python-i-cant-tell-if-this-will-work-or-not)

```
import time
while time.strftime("%b, %d", time.localtime()) != "Dec, 25":
    time.sleep(60)
print "It's Christmas"
```

Python in 115 Characters

## Rules

Here are the rules:

- Assume that the computer's clock is always right.
- Your code must be able to be started at any time.
- Your code must print `"It's Christmas"` on Christmas.
- Looping is certainly not necessary, but once started your code should not stop until it has printed.
- Shortest code wins.

Comment: I thought the input is in Julian date before I read this post

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Unix, 39 bytes

```
echo{,} "It\'s christmas"|at -t12252359
```

With help from Dennis, thanks for that.

Comment: This violates »Looping is certainly not necessary, but once started your code should not stop until it has printed.«, though.

Comment: I don't understand your critique. Do you claim this is looping? That it stops before printing?

Comment: Using `echo{,} "It\'s Christmas"|at -t12252359`, this is shorter than the accepted answer. (The backslash is required by the way.)

Comment: @Dennis: Nice use of brace expansion.

Answer (score 18):

### PowerShell, 45 <s>46</s> chars

```
for(;(date).date-ne'12/25'){}"It's Christmas"
```

It's certainly not very power-efficient, so a laptop battery might die before Christmas (reason to wish for a new one, maybe). But not sleeping is definitely *shorter*.

This is also locale-agnostic. And thanks to Jaykul for a nice trick in reducing this further.

### Abusing the rules a bit, 45 chars

```
for(){"It's Christmas"*((date)-like'12/25*')}
```

This will print empty lines until it's Christmas, upon which it will print “It's Christmas”.

It ...

- ... can be started at any time.
- ... prints “It's Christmas” on Christmas. Several times. The whole day long. (The rules didn't say anything about how often it may be printed.)
- ... does *not* print “It's Christmas” on not-Christmas (although it prints an empty line in that case; can be rectified by sacrificing another character, but then this gains nothing over the more sane solution above).
- ... does not ever stop (not even after it has printed “It's Christmas” but *definitely* not before).

Comment: for(;(date).date-ne"12/25"){}"It's Christmas"  # 45 chars

Comment: Jaykul: Thanks ... that's something I never would have thought to be working.

Comment: The "abusive" script could also use `-match`, and do without the wildcard, for no gain/loss in characters.

Comment: You can remove the abuse now, it's unneeded.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer: How so? It still offers an interesting alternative approach, even though it's not shorter.

Answer (score 18):

### Perl + Unix, 40 chars

```
1until`date`=~/c 25/;say"It's Christmas"
```

This is the same as [J B's Perl solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4110/3191), except that I save a few chars by using the external `date` command instead of Perl's `localtime`.

Answer (score 12):

**PostScript, 90**

```
(%Calendar%)currentdevparams begin{Month 12 eq Day 25 eq and{exit}if}loop(It's Christmas)=
```

Don't run on a printer, it doesn't print a page, and it will only DoS your printer until Christmas day.  Then again, getting your printer back would be a nice present.

Comment: Don't forget to tape a sign to the printer saying: [DO NOT KILL JOB UNTIL CHRISTMAS!](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Killing-Job.aspx)

Comment: I guess most printers won't even have a working hardware clock as that's an optional feature. Very nice, though :)

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 47

```
While[Date[][[2;;3]]!={12,25}];"It's Christmas"
```

Comment: I was surprised that Mathematica doesn't have a built-in for Xmas.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 44 <s>45</s>

```
perl -E'1until localtime=~/c 25/;say"It's Christmas"'
```

Wouldn't GMT time be sufficient? (3 characters off ;-)

Comment: `1until localtime=~/c 25/;` would save you one char. :)

Comment: I thought I'd already tried that and it failed, but it turns out I actually forgot `-E` at the time.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  (Ps. I just posted a version of your solution using backticks instead of `localtime` below.  Feel free to steal it if you like, but I felt the extra dependency justified a separate answer.)

Comment: Naaaw, shame's on me for not thinking of it [again](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/978/199). The separate answer is perfectly justified IMO (and upvoted).

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 45

```
{localtime=~/c 25/&&die"It's Christmas";redo}
```

### Perl, 44

using ternary operator (Thanks to Ilmari Karonen).

```
{localtime=~/c 25/?say"It's Christmas":redo}
```

Comment: `? :` instead of `&& ;` would save you one char too.  (And I'd use `say` instead of `die` for prettier output.)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: thanks. But by using `say` instead of die, the script never finish.

Comment: It will, if you use the ternary operator.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: yes, of course. May be i'm too tired !!!

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript, 51 chars

It's a CPU killer:

```
while(!/c 25/.test(Date()));alert("It's Christmas")
```

Answer (score 5):

## **R (47)**

```
while(!grepl("c 25",date())){};"It's Christmas"
```

Comment: `while(!grepl("c 25",date()))0;"It's Christmas"` is 1 byte shorter.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do this without parsing strings. Subsequently, there's a lot of magic numbers in my code.

I did some approximation to account for leap years. No one said that it had to print it out right on 00:00:00, Dec. 25!

### Perl, <strike>80</strike> <strike>69</strike> 57 characters

```
{(time-30931200)%31557600<86399?die"It's Christmas":redo}
```

Edited for more concise looping!

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 66 <strike>68</strike>

```
import time
while'c 25'not in time.ctime():1
print"It's Christmas"
```

Comment: That `1` at the end of the second line looks quite suspicious to me. :P

Comment: @Trimsty:  The `1` provides a body for the while-loop.  It's basically a busy wait until December 25.  It has the similar effect to `while 1:if'c 25'in time.asctime():break`.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I think `time.ctime()` would do.

Comment: @gnibbler:  Indeed it would.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, <s>42</s> 38

```
Repeat 769=sum(getDate²,2
End
"It's Christmas
```

Expects the date format to be YYYY/MM/DD.

getDate creates a three-element list `{year,month,day}`; only on Christmas is month^2 + day^2 equal to 769.

23 bytes are used for the string because lowercase letters are two bytes each, except for i which is displayed as the imaginary unit token.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch file, 68 chars

```
:l
@date/t|findstr/c:"-12-25">nul&&echo It's Christmas&&exit
@goto l
```

Not usable interactively, as it kills the session. Solving that would require 5 more characters.

Also locale-sensitive. This works on my locale which uses ISO 8601 date format.

But hey, it's a batch file (by most not even regarded as a programming language). And shorter than Javascript (and on par with Python).

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy, 55

```
while(!new Date()==~/.*c 25.*/);
println"It's Christmas"
```

Think it works, but still waiting for output.

Comment: If Groovy's regexps are anything like in most other languages, those `.*` are entirely unnecessary.  (Ps. You can test it by waiting for Dec 5 instead of 25.)

Comment: Ilmari, Groovy is a JVM language and Java's regexes are anchored by default.

Comment: Ilmari, I'd check but my program is still running

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 53

```
until Time.now.to_s=~/c 25/
end
puts"It's Christmas!"
```

Answer (score 2):

### (pdf)eTeX - 180 chars only December 1-25.

```
\lccode`m`~\let\e\expandafter\def~{\ifdim900pt<\pdfelapsedtime
sp\pdfresettimer\else\e~\fi}\lowercase\e{\e\scantokens\e
{\romannumeral\numexpr (25 - \day)*96000}}It's Christmas!\bye
```

TeX only has a way to access the date when the program starts, and the time elapsed since the start, capped at 32768 seconds, so I need to compute the number of seconds to wait, and for each second do a loop which waits for the elapsed time to reach `1s` and reset the time. (Precisely, I'm doing blocks of 900 seconds.)

Working for any month requires more work: 355 chars.

```
\lccode`m=`~\let\o\or\let\y\year\let\n\numexpr\let\e\expandafter
\def\b#1{\ifnum#1=\n(#1/4)*4\relax+1\fi}\def~{\ifdim
900pt<\pdfelapsedtime sp\pdfresettimer\else\e~\fi}\lowercase
\e{\e\scantokens\e{\romannumeral\n(25-\day+\ifcase\month\o334\b\y
\o303\b\y\o275\o244\o214\o183\o153\o122\o91\o61\o30\o0\ifnum25<\day
365\b{\n\y+1}\fi\fi)*96000}}It's Christmas!\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

### MySQL, 180 chars

Because what are you using your database engine for, anyway?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION c() RETURNS CHAR(14) BEGIN a: LOOP IF DAY(NOW())=25 && MONTH(NOW())=12 THEN RETURN 'It\'s Christmas'; END IF; END LOOP a; END$$
DELIMITER ;
SELECT c();
```

Not very competitive lengthwise, but hey, it's doable!

Comment: Try `DELIMITER /`, `RETURNS TEXT` and `CURDATE()LIKE'%12-25'`; and try to remove some whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 40 bytes

```php
<?while(date(dm)-1225);?>It´s Christmas;
```

Loop until 25th of December; then exit to plain mode and print.

Run with default settings (don´t display notices).

Answer (score 2):

## 8086 machine code, 33 bytes

```
00000000  b4 2a cd 21 81 fa 19 0c  75 f6 b4 09 ba 12 01 cd  |.*.!....u.......|
00000010  21 c3 49 74 27 73 20 43  68 72 69 73 74 6d 61 73  |!.It's Christmas|
00000020  24                                                |$|
00000021
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 84 bytes

```forth
: f begin time&date drop 12 = 0<> swap 25 = 0<> and until s" It's Christmas!" type ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lce9CoAgFAbQV/lyqCmooKW/panHMNQSSsV7I3p6I2g6HOMj7@VmPlLqYLDqzTqwPXWuJGuo6APqBiOqYQLdMqBp/0mncDm2B0hg4YIw79ESn5IyAX6CRp9MegE)

Yet another stack language. Somehow not the longest answer.

The `time&date` word is very convenient here.

A stack overflow happens since time&date values are left on stack every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <del>93</del> <del>89</del> <del>78</del> 77 chars

`function x(){Date().match("c 25")?alert("It's Christmas"):setTimeout(x,1)}x()`

Comment: @Joey Thanks! I forgot about that.

Comment: Another non-blocking version: `setInterval('/c 25/.test(Date())&&alert("It\'s Christmas")',9)` at 61 chars ... the only drawback is that it will `alert()` all day on Christmas.

Comment: Why `setInterval` to 1? `setInveral` to `1000*60*60*24` and it both won't make the process suffer and will notify only once on christmas.

Answer (score 1):

### D, 130

```
import std.datetime,std.stdio;
main(){
do{
auto t = Clock.currTime();
}while(t.month!=12||t.day!=25);
writeln("It's Christmas");
}
```

Comment: You can probably save two characters in the assignment. And a few more by reducing the number of lines.

Comment: I can also save some by using `t.month^12|t.day^25` (if I get my priorities right)

Answer (score 1):

### Q, 63 chars

```
system"t 1000";.z.ts:{$["12.25"~-5#-3!.z.d;1"It's Christmas";]}
```

will work for christmas day on every year

Answer (score 1):

## SQL*Plus + PL/SQL - 100

```
EXEC LOOP EXIT WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DDMM')='2512';END LOOP;DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('It''s Christmas');
```

- Assuming `SERVEROUTPUT ON`
- Shorter then the MySql solution (eat that, MySql!)
- Too late for last year, but in time for this year
- Tried `DBMS_OUTPUT.put` instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` but that doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

### C# (126)

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){while(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("Md")!="1225");Console.WriteLine("It's Christmas");}}
```

Nicer for your battery:

### C# (163)

```
using s=System;class P{static void Main(){s.Threading.Thread.Sleep(s.DateTime.ParseExact("1225","Md",null)-s.DateTime.Now);s.Console.WriteLine("It's Christmas");}}
```

*edit*

The second ("nicer for your battery") version does have a bit of an issue dec. 26th to dec. 31st I just thought of :P

Both versions can probably be shortened a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```
DTREAD OUT,M,D?"It's Christmas"*(M/D==.48)EXEC.
```

`month/day` will be `0.48` on December 25th.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 27 bytes

```
Ks f"c 25" ?`It's CËItµs`:P
```

To test against today's date : Replace `c 25` with this month's last letter (shorthand) + space + day of the month. `Feb 02` == `b 02`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@9drJCmlKxgZKqkYO@fouRZol6s4Hy427Pk0NZiJQWrgP//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 58 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediates window function that takes no input and runs until it's Christmas day, at which time it outputs `It's Christmas` to the VBE immediates window.

```
While Left(Now,5)<>"12/25":DoEvents:Wend:?"It's Christmas"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <sup><s>28</s></sup> 21 bytes

```
[že25Qžf12Q&#}”It'sŒÎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@ui@VCPTwKP70gyNAtWUax81zPUsUS8@Oulw3///AA)

Noncompeting, I suppose(Beats the other non-competing answer, ha).

My first 05AB1E answer.

-7 bytes from ovs.

### Explanation

```
[že25Qžf12Q&#”It'sŒÎ
[                            start an infinite loop
 že                          push current day
   25                        25
     Q                       are they equal?
      žf                     push current month
        12                   12
          Q                  are they equal?
           &                 logical and
            #                break if both conditions are true
             ”It'sŒÎ         push "It's Christmas"
                             implicit output
```

Comment: This will not output *It's Christmas* is the execution is started on Christmas, since `"It's Christmas` is part of the loop and won't get executed if `#` breaks on the first iteration. This can be fixed by closing the loop after `#` with `}`.

Comment: And with the help of [Kevin's tip on compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/64121), the string literal can be shortened to `”It'sŒÎ`.

Comment: @Shaggy It loops infinitely and breaks on christmas. When it breaks, it prints the value. I think it's correct.

Comment: Sorry, @Razetime, missed the infinite loop at the start :\

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(kNkM,¿⁺P¿Q)’It's ñẈmas
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPShrTmtNJTJDJUMyJUJGJUUyJTgxJUJBUCVDMiVCRlEpJUUyJTgwJTk5SXQncyUyMCVDMyVCMSVFMSVCQSU4OG1hcyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
(kNkM,¿⁺P¿Q)’It's ñẈmas  '# Full program
(          )              # Loop until this returns false:
 kNkM,                    #   Push [current month, current day]
      ¿⁺P¿Q               #   Not equal to [12, 25]
            ’It's ñẈmas  '# Push "It's Christmas"
                          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

#### bash-n-date: 69 chars:

```
sleep $(($(date -d"12/25" +%s)-$(date +%s))) && echo "It's X-Ray    "
```

But it will fail on Dec. 26th to Dec. 31th.

Answer (score 0):

### Q (60)

```
 system"t 1000";.z.ts:{if[.z.d~2012.12.25;1"It’s Christmas"]}
```

Comment: > If it is not Christmas, you must somehow wait until Christmas and then print "It's Christmas".

Comment: My apologies, corrected to check every second if it's Christmas...so this will print "It's Christmas" 86,400 times every 25th December. Obviously you can alter this by increasing the timer, which is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 49 Characters

I got this quite short, so yeah.

```
<?while(date("dm")!="2512");echo"It's Christmas";
```

EDIT: Whoops, I printed something else than `It's Christmas` x3

Answer (score 0):

### Rebol (53 chars)

```
wait difference 25-Dec-14 now
print "It's Christmas"
```

Of course the above will only wait till Xmas 2014 :)

Here's a version that will wait for next Xmas day:

```
next-xmas: does [
    d: now
    make date! reduce [25 12 either all [d/month = 12 d/day > 25][d/year + 1][d/year]]
]

wait difference next-xmas now
print "It's Christmas"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-98 (36 chars)

Requires a Unicode-capable interpreter (`'` is used for a literal 65536 and `'ఙ` for 3097):

```
aa+y'%'ఙ-!#v_
s Christmas"<@,kd"It'
```

Explanation:

- Use `y` with an argument of 20 to get the date field (`aa+y`)
- Mask off the month & day portion by reducing mod-65536 (`'%`)
- Subtract 3097 (= *month* * 256 + *day*) (`'ఙ-`)
- If zero, print the string (abuses edge wrapping)
- Otherwise repeat

Comment: Since default code-golf scoring is now in bytes, this should be at least 39 due to the multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

#### J, 54

```
'It''s Christmas'[(-^:(3 :'-.12 25-:1 2{6!:0''''')^:_)1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `calendar.holidays.us math.unicode`, 54 bytes

```
[ now dup christmas-day ≠ ] loop [I It's ChristmasI]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PYsxCsIwGEav8m1O7Siio6BkcRGn0uEnSWkwzV-SP4hH8AwuWfROXT2JgtXp8eC9-7MjLRzLtDsd1WG_hiZvg6GIs43B-r_XPXtn6JrqnDCQ9HUOTrOxcEFsHNmTWGweWbpqNS0bBL7A5BG6jy7JQKn63HjdClp45hGNgpJFwvYXqPZ7lxkz3w)

Answer (score -2):

## Groovy - 88

```
new Timer().schedule({print"It's Christmas"}as TimerTask,Date.parse("yyddMM","112512"))
```

Comment: Is all that whitespace necessary?

Comment: @Joey no, it was for the sake of readability.

Comment: Does it work every year? Don't think so.