# Friday the 13th

Tags: code-golf

This post would make more sense if it were Friday the 13th today... But oh well.

Write a full program that, given any year as the input from at least -10,000 to 10,000, prints all dates of that year that are Friday and also on the 13th of the month.

Output can be expressed as MM/dd, dd/MM, dd.MM, or any other readable format which clearly indicates the month and day.

Keep leap years in mind! Every four years an extra day is added to February unless it is the turn of the century and the year is NOT divisible by 400 evenly (the year 2000 has a leap year, 1900 or 2100 do not (since they aren't divisible by 400)).

Also even though the Gregorian calendar as we know it didn't exist before 1582, any year before that should still reveal the dates as if it did exist.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Relevant [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A157962).

Comment: Isn't requesting output to be "MM/dd" or the like redundant, since every `dd` is going to be `13`?

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69510/superstitious-programming Also, are date-builtins allowed?